# Sparkjava jetty server Android application problem access ssl secure webserver

Tags: android, embedded-jetty, spark-java

I use this code keystor is .bks file (Android):

```
secure(KEYSTORE_FILE.getAbsolutePath(), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD,null,null);
get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
```

When i try to access https://192.168.0.24/hello on my browser, i get connexion failed.

Also, i try:

```
  curl -v --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.3 https://192.168.0.24/hello

      Trying 192.168.0.24:443...
     * TCP_NODELAY set
     * connect to 192.168.0.24 port 443 failed: Connexion refusée
     * Failed to connect to 192.168.0.24 port 443: Connexion refusée
     * Closing connection 0
     curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.24 port 443: Connexion refusée
```

Do you know what is the problem please?

Without secure, it's works fine with http protocol.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using the domain associated to the certificate instead of the IP?

Answer (score 0):

TLS only works with domain names, not IP addresses or localhost.

Use the hostname in your certificate.

Comment: So how can i use if i apply in local network with my mobile phone?

Comment: This is a built-in and hard security enforcement of the Java implementation of TLS.   You really cannot work around it, you have to follow it's rules.   There is also a similar enforcement on the browser side (Chrome and Firefox perform similar enforcement checks when doing TLS)